Windows authentication for SQL server using SQlServerDriver and Springboot JDBCTemplate
we want to connect to SQL server data base using windows authentication. we are able to connect with SQL server authentication, but the password is getting changed very frequently and our application is failing
i have following dependencies for JDBCTemplate and ms-sql driver in pom.xml
my parent is spring-boot-starter-parent of version 2.7.18 and we use java 11

    <dependency>
       <artifactid>org.springboot</artifactid>
       <groupid>spring-jdbc</groupid>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <artifactid>com.microsoft.sqlserver</artifactid>
      <groupid>mssql-jdbc</groupid>
    </dependency>


In My application.yml file i have like this
spring:
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:sqlserver://hostName:portNumber;databaseName=dbName;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertficate=true;
     username:username
     password:password

in my database configuration
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
String url;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
String username;
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
String password;

    @Bean 
    public Datasource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource=new 
       DriverManagerDataSource();  
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUserName(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean 
    public JDBCTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        return new JDBCTemplate(dataSource);
    }


using the above the code is not working the authentication is failing with Error Failed to obtain JDBC connection .
nested Exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException : Login failed.
the login is from untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication.
when i use SQLserver authentication by changing my YML file to below the code is working as expected but failing when the password changes.
spring:
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:sqlserver://hostName:portNumber;databaseName=dbName;trustServerCertfication=true;
     username:username
     password:password

we have other application where we don't use JDBCTemplate and gets connection by  using
public Connection getConnection(){
try{
   class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");
 Connection=DriverManeger.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://hostName:portNumber;databaseName=dbName;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertfication=true;", username,password);
}
 
catch(Exception e){
 log.error("Exception occurred : {}",e.getMessage());

  } 
}


with this connection is successful and able to query the result set. But we are using JDBCTemplate and want to use windows Authentication.

You should be able to create SQLServerDataSource and set the same parameters as you do in the "raw" getConnection-jdbc url. Btw, it's not trustServerCertfication but rather trustServerCertificate

Thanks @siggemannen, i edited the url. I tied configuring SQLServerDataSource and then i got error Failed to obtain JDBC connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerException: This driver is not configured for windows Authentication

You need to add the dll for windows auth to the class path, which probably other applications do

Thanks @siggemannen ,where can i find that DLL file?, we use windows for local testing, and we deploy in Unix servers and run our applications in server. can we get that DLL file though any maven dependency? we don't have internet access to download something on our office machine.

Yes, it's in maven, you should probably just work through the microsoft jdbc docs, it's all spelled out there. But as i wrote before, if you already have apps which successfully use windows auth, why not just follow whatever they are doing? It should be same
